Where did sys.modules go?
>>> import sys
>>> del sys.modules['sys']
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'modules'

Why does re-imported sys module not have some attributes anymore?
I am using Python 3.12.3 and it happens in macOS, Linux, and Windows. It happens in both the REPL and in a .py script. It does not happen in Python 3.11.

How the heck did this even happen? I can’t reproduce it (python 3.9.16, and 3.11.0)

@dragoncoder047 For me it was not reproducible in a module, but it was inside the REPL. (mine is 3.12)

It's not a normal behavior for all modules. There has to be some sort of hidden works with sys in particular. I don't know why

There's probably something special about how the REPL manages its namespace, which is different from how normal file-based namespaces work when running scripts.

There are some special modules in Python, like builtins. sys may also get special treatment.

I can reproduce this in a script and on the REPL on 3.12.3. I also tried 3.11-3.8.

It's not alone, looks like about half of all attributes get lost that way.

It seems that some attributes of the sys module are not defined standard way (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/37d095002216a4e45b4e82539ca0421ded8aaae3/Python/sysmodule.c#L2519). E.g. the "modules" attribute is added only when interpreter is initialized (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/37d095002216a4e45b4e82539ca0421ded8aaae3/Python/sysmodule.c#L3774C22-L3774C23)

I can't reproduce this under Windows with either command line or IDLE (3.11.0) or on WSL2 Ubuntu command line (3.8.10).

@MarkRansom Try in 3.12

"Doctor, it hurts when I do this!" "Don't do that" -- is there code one would write in a real-world environment where this would ever come up?

@CharlesDuffy That's irrelevant to the question of "why does it happen".

@nosteponsnek, but it is relevant to the question of whether "why does it happen?" is on-topic here at all. Questions are required to be practical in nature.

See also, on [meta.se], What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design? -- this isn't a language design question as such, but similarly, it isn't something that can be reasonably expected to have an answer that changes how one goes about the practice of software development.

How sys is initialized is definitely on topic for [python-internals] ("How does Python work underneath the hood?").

@CharlesDuffy By understanding the failure mode, you can gain a better intuition about when/why/how it may be unreliable to reload a module. I think that's a good practical knowledge to have.

This is pretty obviously something you shouldn't do, naturally liable to break things. It happens to break things this particular way on the Python implementation you tried, but Python doesn't promise what will happen. Most of what I am about to say is implementation details.

The sys module cannot be initialized like normal built-in modules, as it's responsible for so much core functionality. Instead, on interpreter startup, Python creates the sys module with the special function _PySys_Create. This function is responsible for (part of the job of) correctly setting up the sys module, including the sys.modules attribute:
    if (PyDict_SetItemString(sysdict, "modules", modules) < 0) {
        goto error;
    }

When you do del sys.modules['sys'], the import system loses track of the sys module. When you try to import it again, Python tries to create an entirely new sys module, and it does so as if sys were an ordinary built-in module. It goes through the procedure for initializing ordinary built-in modules. This procedure leaves the new sys module in an inconsistent, improperly initialized state, as sys was never designed to be initialized this way.
There is support for reloading sys, although I believe the dev team is thinking of taking this support out - the use cases are very obscure, and the only one I can think of off the top of my head is obsolete. Part of the reinitialization ends up hitting a code path intended for reloading sys, which updates its __dict__ from a copy created early in the original initialization of sys, right before sys.modules is set:
    interp->sysdict_copy = PyDict_Copy(sysdict);
    if (interp->sysdict_copy == NULL) {
        goto error;
    }

    if (PyDict_SetItemString(sysdict, "modules", modules) < 0) {
        goto error;
    }

This copy is handled differently on earlier Python versions, hence the version-related behavior differences.

But _PySys_Create was there in 3.11 too. What changed in 3.12?

@nosteponsnek: Answer expanded.
